# Cannot get a basic Casbah 3.0 program to compile

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

My project uses the following jars: scala-library (2.9.2), mongo-java-driver (2.7.3), scalaj-collection (2.9.1-1.2), casbah (util, commons, core, query, gridfs) 2.9.1-3.0.0-M2, joda-time 2.1, and joda convert 1.2

When I enter the following hello-worldish code:

```
package test

import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var connection = MongoConnection()
  }
}
```

I get an error: "not found: value MongoConnection". The error goes away if I explicitly

```
include com.mongodb.casbah.MongoConnection
```

But I thought `Imports._` was supposed to be taking care of that. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What are you using to build this? I get this sort of thing randomly within eclipse sometimes (with the auto-build red squiggly underline), but using SBT to build works fine.

Comment: Yes, I use Eclipse, and the latest version of the Scala IDE plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Casbah 3.0, `Imports._` is deprecated.
What is weird though is that MongoConnection is not even imported anymore. Everything else works but deprecation warnings occur.

As those warnings state, you just need to do this instead:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah._
```

Comment: No idea, sorry. The only thing to do would be to get the source code and generate the scaladoc (with `sbt doc`). Sadly I didn't found anything summing up the differences between 2.1.5 and 3.0.